# Reinstanciating a class inside the class in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example, if I have the class:

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, bar):
        self.bar = bar
        self.baz = self.bar + "foo"

    def restart(self, value):
        # reinstanciate the class with new value (bar) function ???
```

How can I get this functionality so that the class can be reinstanciated but stay in the same instance (`ex`)?

```py
ex = Foo("baz")
print(ex.bar)
# "baz"
print(ex.baz)
# "bazfoo"

ex.restart("qux")
print(ex.bar)
# "qux"
print(ex.baz)
# "quxfoo"
```

Answer (score 1):

You just want to *reinitialize* the value; define a separate method to set `bar` and `baz`, so that you can call it from `__init__` as well as call it explicitly.

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, bar):
        self.initialize(bar)

    def initialize(self, value):
        self.bar = value
        self.baz = value + "foo"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, is to use *properties*. That way you need to assign only one value:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, bar):
        self._bar = bar

    @property
    def bar(self):
        return self._bar

    @property
    def baz(self):
        return self._bar + "foo"

    def restart(self, value):
        self._bar = value
```

Usage is exactly the same like in your question:

```
ex = Foo("baz")
print(ex.bar)
# "baz"
print(ex.baz)
# "bazfoo"

ex.restart("qux")
print(ex.bar)
# "qux"
print(ex.baz)
# "quxfoo"
```